# How to make visible a button in a jQuery DataTable column by data in another column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to set the button in another column to be visible / hidden according to the status data in one column of the data table.

I tried this:

```
{
                targets: 6,
                data: null,
                orderable: false,
                defaultContent: '',
                rowAction: {
                    element:
                            $("<button/>")
                            .addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger")
                            .text(app.localize('SendToDepartments'))
                            .click(function () {
                                debugger;
                                var id = $(this).data().id;
                                _sendToDepartmentsModal.open({ id });
                            }),
                    visible: function () {
                        debugger;
                        var status = _$annotationDepartmentInboxFromManagerTable
                            .row()
                            .data().status;
                        
                        if (status != 'Sent To Departments') {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

But this changes the visibility of the buttons on all rows.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, I used render :

```
  render: function (data, type, full, meta) {                     
                        if (full.status != 'Sent To Departments') {
                            return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-name="' + full.id + '">' + "click!"+'</button>';
                        }
                        else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
```